# CSRF token missing or incorrect (I know, its been asked before!)

Tags: python, django, csrf

Been two days trolling through Google, stackoverflow, and docs.djangoproject.com for a solution to CSRF problems.

**Disclaimer, am a beginner at Django and following along the book *The definitive guide to django - web development done right.* Well, apparently am getting something wrong  :-(**

See below one such attempt and see if you can point out any mistakes because I've tried all the suggestions on stackoverflow but no luck as yet:

***view.py:***

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def add_vehicle(request):
    return render_to_response('vehicle.html', RequestContext(request, {}))
```

***vehicle.html:***

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Vehicle Registration{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/vehicle/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <table width=100%>
        <tr>
            <td>Reg #:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="regnumber"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Model:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="model"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Manufacturer:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="manufacturer"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Year:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="year"></td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Chassis #:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="chasisnumber"></td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Clear">
            </td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

*I hope that's not too much code for stackoverflow.*

Now, I keep getting the ***CSRF token missing or incorrect***.

Please assist.

**Edit (Adding details on error)**

*settings.py looks like this:*

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Here is what the console displays when I open vehicle.html page:

```
warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.")
```

Comment: -1: "I know, its been asked before!"  But you refused to search for it or reference it?  That's rude.

Comment: Sorry for appearing rude. But I'd looked at all the questions asked and all the answers provided and felt adding another question on the same was wrong but I didn't have an alternative. Actually the aim was telling peeps that I appreciate the question is a repeat but with no answer to my specific case. My bad

Comment: Do you have multiple Django sites running in mod_wsgi under Apache?

Comment: @S.Lott: No. Only got one site. I haven't even setup Apache yet. Using the default web server that ships with django. thanks.

Comment: Two MORE things.  (1) Be **very** careful when copying and pasting code.  Your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is missing some quotes.  Either your code is bad or you didn't copy and paste carefully.  (2) Since you're having problems with the `RequestContext`, you need to review https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext.  The code you have posted is **NOT** exactly like the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature for render_to_response is `render_to_response(template_name[, dictionary][, context_instance][, mimetype])` so should you be calling it like the following to ensure the csrf token is put into the context?

```
return render_to_response('vehicle.html', {}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))`
```

Comment: @lukik: Please include the error message in the **question** as an **update**.  Do not add critical facts as comments.

Comment: @lukik: The code you have posted is not **exactly** like this answer.  Please fix your code and **update** the question to show the actual code you are actually using.

Comment: @S.Lott: Thanks for the patience! I've repasted without extra reformatting.

Comment: This is correct -- you *cannot* just use a RequestContext instance as a random parameter to render_to_response. It needs to be either the third unnamed parameter, or it needs to be named 'context_instance' explicitly.

Comment: @lukik: You are aware that the `add_vehicle` function in the question remains the source of the problem?   The "I've put it exactly like you have" in your comment is incorrect; please remove the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the insistence. The error was actually elsewhere as I'd already changed to what @sandinmyjoints had recommended. But' I'd changed it in the wrong view. In `urlpatterns` had a url pointin to `/vehicle/` and another pointing to `/add_vehicle/`. I kept on changing the view for `add_vehicle` while all along I should have changed the one pointing to `/vehicle/`. So kept getting it wrong! Silly me. After u pointed it out, I went back to scratch, even reading the "Templates Chapter" again. I started verifying all entries again and then realized the blunder. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You're not the first to make a mistake like that! Glad you persisted and figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

You may be missing the middle ware

Comment: I have the middleware:  

**settings.py**  
    'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (  
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',  
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  
    )'

Comment: @lukik: Please include the code sample in the **question** as an **update**.  Do not add code in comments.